# MDT 2013 - Client not picking up new Unattend.xml settings

Tags: deployment, wds, mdt

I'm deploying a new image via MDT 2013. I created a new Task Sequence using an existing image and tested it on a VM. I ended up getting the "Unattend.xml Error - Could not parse or process for pass [specialize]..." error. I went in and checked, and the "IEWelcomeMsg" is not set to write the value. I double checked in the Control folder and the Unattend XML file doesn't have that value:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-IE-InternetExplorer" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Home_Page>about:blank</Home_Page>
<DisableWelcomePage>true</DisableWelcomePage>
<DisableFirstRunWizard>false</DisableFirstRunWizard>
</component>
```

But when I look at the client, I'm seeing some old settings:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-IE-InternetExplorer" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Home_Page>about:blank</Home_Page>
<IEWelcomeMsg>false</IEWelcomeMsg>
<DisableWelcomePage>true</DisableWelcomePage>
</component>
```

Any idea why it isn't picking up the new unattend.xml settings? Just to be clear, I did rebuild the deployment share after making any changes.

---

For some added confusion, I tried deleting the C:\Windows\Panther\Unattend.xml to make sure a new one was used. When I did that, it picked up my new settings (DisableFirstRunWizard for instance), but kept the IEWelcomeMsg that doesn't exist in the server XML file. Here is what the client has in the XML now:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-IE-InternetExplorer" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Home_Page>about:blank</Home_Page>
<IEWelcomeMsg>false</IEWelcomeMsg>
<DisableWelcomePage>true</DisableWelcomePage>
<DisableFirstRunWizard>false</DisableFirstRunWizard>
</component>
```

Comment: Did you update the unattend.xml in the Task Sequence folder?

Comment: Also: Did you update your deployment share? I recommend rebuilding from scratch (in update options).

Comment: Yes, I did update the deployment. I'll give force update a try.

Comment: Also to clarify your xml is not being updated? or are your settings not being applied to the vm?

Comment: Originally, it wasn't updating the XML file at all. After deleting the XML off the client machine, it got the new file. But the <IEWelcomeMsg> value showed up on the client. Strange because that value is nowhere in the server copy of the XML file.

Comment: So you have completed a full image rebuild?
Also: Are there any custom files that you are using?

Comment: I did a force on the Deployment Share update, deleted the unattend.xml from the client (just to be sure) and then re-deployed. Same thing. The <IEWelcomeMsg> shows up in the client XML file. What do you mean by custom files? I made some changes to the XML file if thats what you mean.

Comment: There are also some other values showing up in the client XML that don't exist in the server XML. For instance, the account to join the computer to a domain shows up in the client XML, but it doesn't exist in the server XML. Is there something else in MDT that controls the client XML values?

Comment: Did you find the answer?